# AWS ALB Cognito JWT/OIDC authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

We are trying to integrate AWS ALB with Cognito user pool. We have setup rules in ALB to authenticate user with Cognito client. After webapp authentication, a session cookie is set. This is all good.

Now, we have a desktop application which does internally connect with Cognito, get access token JWT and manage it (refresh etc.). Now, we are trying to fire http requests to ALB with this access token as Authorization header. ALB redirect these requests to Cognito login page again, instead of validating (and allowing) the JWT present in Auth header.

What we expect is if request contains valid Auth header (JWT), ALB should first validate it and then allow it, if successfully authentiated. It seems ALB does not check Auth header. How can we achieve this with ALB?
Additionally, is it possible for desktop app to work directly with ALB (instead of Cognito) and use Session ID instead of JWT/Access Token?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you've followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html) and have set up a single listener rule with actions `authenticate-cognito` and `forward`.

If yes, then I believe that the best solution is to add a *higher priority* rule that has a [host header condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#http-header-conditions).

If you do this, the authorization code on your back-end will have to look for both the `Authorization` and `x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken`.

Comment: Yes, I followed the these instructions. With your suggestion, would ALB do the authentication using provided auth header? Or my back-end needs to take care of it?

Comment: @NumeroUno - at this time ALB does not support the ability to deny requests based on a JWT (unlike API Gateway), so yes, you'll need to validate on the back end. That's a good idea anyway, especially if you use multiple Cognito user pools with different applications (to avoid problems with a misconfigured ALB).